# HTTP request path is empty (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am new to ruby programming.  This is my first program in Watir.  When I execute the code below, I am getting `HTTP request path is empty (ArgumentError)`. Appreciate your help in fixing this error.  I am accessing internet through proxy settings.  I have added `HTTP_PROXY` variable in environment variables to http://myproxy.mynetwork.net:8008/

### test.rb

```
require "watir"
require "rubygems"
require "rspec"
require "watir-webdriver"

puts "Hello,World...!" 

@browser = Watir::Browser.new
@browser.goto("http://www.google.com")   
@browser.close
puts "Browser should have been closed.."
```

### Output

```
d:\>ruby test.rb
Hello,World...!
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1860:in `initialize': HTTP request path is
 empty (ArgumentError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2093:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.41.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:71:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.41.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:71:in `new_request_for'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.41.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:35:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.41.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:64:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.41.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.41.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:634:in `raw_execute'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.41.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:99:in `create_session'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.41.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:68:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.41.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/firefox/bridge.rb:36:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.41.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:31:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.41.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:31:in `for'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.41.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver.rb:67:in `for'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.9/lib/watir
-webdriver/browser.rb:46:in `initialize'
        from test.rb:8:in `new'
        from test.rb:8:in `<main>'
```

Firefox browser window is getting opened.  After that the address bar is not changing, and it is getting closed after some time.

Comment: FWIW: you don't need to (and shouldn't) `require 'watir'` and `require 'watir-webdriver'`.  The [watir](https://github.com/watir/watir) gem is a meta-gem that encompasses both watir-classic and watir-webdriver.

Comment: I'm having this same issue.  Have you been able to solve it yet?

Answer (score 1):

net/http require a valid path. So you have to put a trailing slash at the end of the URL, like this:

```
@browser.goto("http://www.google.com/")
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have added HTTP_PROXY variable in environment variables to
>   http://myproxy.mynetwork.net:8008/

Removing my HTTP_PROXY variable from my (Windows) user/system env settings helped! 
am not sure why this is causing the issue with selenium..

Answer (score 0):

The following steps helped me:

1. Remove HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY variables from my system (User Variables)
2. Restarted my terminal for the changes to take effect.

That's about it! No more errors!